# Use Mercurial path as just part of URL

Tags: url, mercurial, mercurial-subrepos

I am messing around with the paths section of my `.hgrc`, and have `default` and `default:pushurl` set. I am adding another path simply called `def` for now, that is essentially `http://example.com/hg`. Each repository, however, is a subdirectory of this site, i.e. `http://example.com/hg/myrepo`. Is there some way to push and pull using `def` as the first part of the URL? I'd imagine it would look something like `hg pull def/myrepo`, but this particular syntax doesn't work of course. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible with the [Schemes extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/SchemesExtension).

Add the following to your .hgrc:

```
[extensions]
hgext.schemes=

[schemes]
def = http://example.com/hg/
```

Then you'll be able to do `hg push def://myrepo`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this looks like exactly what I want. However, I added the two lines and now get `abort: no '://' in scheme url 'def:myrepo'`. Is there some different formatting I must use?

Comment: Ah, figured it out. The url for `def` must have a trailing `/`.

Comment: Oh, and one more thing. When doing `hg push` or `hg pull`, the syntax is `def://myrepo`.